# Windows 10 specific crash on call LeaveCriticalSection

Tags: c++, multithreading, winapi, windows-10, critical-section

I stucked into a problem with threads syncronization and critical sections on Windows 10.

Application will crash in this case:

- Application has two threads.
- Thread 1 calls EnterCriticalSection with object m_CS
- Thread 2 then attempts to enter the same critical section
- Thread 1 terminates Thread 2 using TerminateThread
- Thread 1 calls LeaveCriticalSection

In previous Windows versions which I was able to test (7, 8, 8.1) this works properly. Thread 2 terminates, and Thread 1 leaves the critical section without exception.

On Windows 10, when Thread 1 leaves the critical section, application crashes with Access Violation. It only happens when another thread was terminated while waiting on EnterCriticalThread.

Looking at the stack trace it looks this (latest frame at the top):

```
RtlpWakeByAddress
RtlpUnWaitCriticalSection
RtlLeaveCriticalSection
```

I spent so much time on debugging this issue. In my case m_CS is totally fine when LeaveCriticalSection was called. I debugged and spent some time to analyze disassembled code of ntdll.dll functions. Seems like object corrupts somewhere during execution of RtlpUnWaitCriticalSection and then passed to RtlpWakeByAddress when crash occurs. Basicly ntdll.dll was able to modify CRITICAL_SECTION object's properties such as lock count in RtlLeaveCriticalSection.

From the web I didn't find any answer on this or statement what changed in Windows 10. Only thread on reddit and ~1800 crash reports for Mozilla Firefox with same call stack in the last month. I contacted with author of post on reddit and he was not able to fix this thus far.

So anybody dealed with this issue and may be have a fix for it or advices? As a solution right now I only see to rethink usage of WinAPI TerminateThread and try to avoid it as much as possible. Another way probably to do a code refactoring and think on application's architecture.

Any response appreciated. 
Thanks in advance

Comment: Why not simply use proper synchronization mechanisms? TerminateThread is more of a last resort mechanism.

Comment: @RudolfsBundulis, Thanks for the response. Honestly the application have really old code and it was added a long time ago. I mentioned that I'm thinking on it right now. But want to hear any feedback if someone able to fix it and have any solution rather the do a lot of work on refactoring.

Comment: @tikhon_k: This is just one of those things that happens with `TerminateThread`.  You may find a workaround for Windows 10 build X, but that isn't even guaranteed to work with Windows 10 build X+1. You did not find documentation on what changed in Windows 10, because implementation details change all the time. Therefore, don't rely on them.

Comment: [Windows started picking up the really big pieces of TerminateThread garbage on the sidewalk, but it’s still garbage on the sidewalk](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20150814-00/?p=91811). TL;DR: `TerminateThread` is a **horrible** idea. The only viable fix is to stop calling `TerminateThread`.

Comment: "I spent so much time on debugging this issue" :) when bug is very easy for understand (from my view)

Comment: @RbMm, May be. But when you got a large project with lot of existed code by many developers and you have only a crash dump, it's hard to understand what's going on here. I understand that TerminateThread is a horrible idea. I must say that most of the time I spent on code analysis in project and only after some time I figured out that the TerminateThread triggers the problem. Ofc terminated thread wasn't in the crash dump. If you are coding from scratch, yep, agree, that's easy to figure out.

Comment: @tikhon_k - yes, you partially right. however when i view RtlpWakeByAddress in stack - i understand what happens after several second. i describe it in self answer. but with knowledge of TerminateThread - this is very important here for understand

Comment: Never ever call `TerminateThread` source: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20150814-00/?p=91811

Comment: @RichardCritten: [Old news](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39635817/windows-10-specific-crash-on-call-leavecriticalsection#comment66576989_39635817).

Answer (score 8):

Implementation of `CRITICAL_SECTION` very volatile from version to version. when in last Windows version thread begin wait on `CRITICAL_SECTION` he call [`WaitOnAddress`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh706898(v=vs.85).aspx) function. ok, really it ntdll internal implementation - `RtlpWaitOnAddress`, but this not change gist. this function internal call `RtlpAddWaitBlockToWaitList` - and here the key point - WaitBlock is allocated on thread stack and pointer to this wait block is added to List. then when owner of `CRITICAL_SECTION` leave he call [`WakeByAddressSingle`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh706900(v=vs.85).aspx) (really it internal implementation `RtlpWakeByAddress`) and this function pop the first WaitBlock from List, extract thread Id from it and call `NtAlertThreadByThreadId`(new api from win 8.1) - for awaken some thread waited in `EnterCriticalSection`. but when you terminated thread, waited in `EnterCriticalSection` - his stack is deallocated. so address of WaitBlock block become invalid. so thread which called `RtlpWakeByAddres`s (as part of `LeaveCriticalSection`) got access violation when try read thread Id from WaitBlock (died thread stack).
conclusion - if you call `TerminatedThread` - process already become in unstable state, bug can be at any time and any point. so - not call this function, especially from self process.

Answer (score 5):

> Thread 1 terminates Thread 2 using TerminateThread

Don't do that. It may look like it works on other windows versions, but there's no way for you to know for sure what side-effects are occurring and hiding from you.

From https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686717(v=vs.85).aspx

> TerminateThread is a dangerous function that should only be used in
>   the most extreme cases. You should call TerminateThread only if you
>   know exactly what the target thread is doing, and you control all of
>   the code that the target thread could possibly be running at the time
>   of the termination. For example, TerminateThread can result in the
>   following problems:
>
> - If the target thread owns a critical section, the critical section will not be released.
> - If the target thread is allocating memory from the heap, the heap lock will not be released.
> - If the target thread is executing certain kernel32 calls when it is terminated, the kernel32 state for the thread's process could be
>     inconsistent.
> - If the target thread is manipulating the global state of a shared DLL, the state of the DLL could be destroyed, affecting other users of
>     the DLL.

What you should do is communicate with thread 2 and let thread 2 shut itself down correctly and safely.

Answer (score 1):

I would change the code of thread 2 to use [`TryEnterCriticalSection`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686857(v=vs.85).aspx)

```
if(!TryEnterCriticalSection(&m_CS)) {
    return 0;    // Terminate thread
}
//code
LeaveCriticalSection(&m_CS);
```

This has the advantage that thread 2 is not waiting on the critical section, and it can terminate itself properly. It is generally not advisable to use `TerminateThread`, as already mentioned by others in the comments.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I can confirm this behavior and spent more than 3 days for finding a memoryleak in our code what distroys my `CRITICAL_SECTION`. The problem was an old call of TerminateThread. The program worked nice, but now on Windows10 we had apparently occuring access violations in `EnterCriticalSection` or `LeaveCriticalSection`.
Thank you so much, this made my day.