# TerminateThread() with CloseHandle() on thread which uses only stack plain variables (without alloc) leaks memory?

Tags: c++, c, winapi

I've created simple test which creates two thread; first one (*WorkerThreadFun*) executes infinite loop and second one (*WorkerGuardThreadFun*) terminates it with small timeout.

Thread to be terminated does not seem to do expicit allocation (at least inside *WorkerThreadFun*) and uses only stack variables of plain C type so I hope the stack will be deallocated by *TerminateThread*() with *CloseHandle*().

By some reason this test leaks memory on my Win7.

Where is the unbalanced heap allocation?

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <synchapi.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define STK_SIZE 4097

typedef enum
{
    GRD_IDLE,
    GRD_READY,
    GRD_TASKSTARTING,
    GRD_TASKWAITING
} GuardThreadState;

typedef struct
{
    HANDLE mHworkerThread;
    HANDLE mHworkerGroupThread;

    volatile int mIsWorkerStarted;

    GuardThreadState mGuardThreadState;

    CRITICAL_SECTION mLock;
    CONDITION_VARIABLE mThreadReadyCond;
    CONDITION_VARIABLE mStartTaskCond;
    CONDITION_VARIABLE mTaskFinishedCond;
} WorkerThreadHolder;

/*
typedef VOID(WINAPI *PRtlFreeUserThreadStack)(HANDLE hProcess, HANDLE hThread);
static PRtlFreeUserThreadStack RtlFreeUserThreadStack = NULL;
*/

DWORD WINAPI WorkerThreadFun(_In_ LPVOID p);
DWORD WINAPI WorkerGuardThreadFun(_In_ LPVOID p);

void Start(WorkerThreadHolder *workerThreadHolderPtr);
void ExecuteTask(WorkerThreadHolder *workerThreadHolderPtr);

/*----------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

DWORD WINAPI WorkerThreadFun(_In_ LPVOID p)
{
    /* use stack variables only in this thread in hope the stack will be deallocated by TerminateThread() */
    WorkerThreadHolder *workerThreadHolderPtr = (WorkerThreadHolder *)p;
    volatile int i;

    workerThreadHolderPtr->mIsWorkerStarted = 1;
    /*WakeAllConditionVariable(&workerThreadHolderPtr->mThreadReadyCond);*/

    /* do nothing for infinite long time */
    for(i = 0;; ++i)
        i = i;

    /*WakeAllConditionVariable(&workerThreadHolderPtr->mTaskFinishedCond);*/

    return 0;
}

DWORD WINAPI WorkerGuardThreadFun(_In_ LPVOID p)
{
    const DWORD taskExecutionTimeoutInMillisec = 1;
    WorkerThreadHolder *workerThreadHolderPtr = (WorkerThreadHolder *)p;

    EnterCriticalSection(&workerThreadHolderPtr->mLock);

    workerThreadHolderPtr->mGuardThreadState = GRD_READY;

    WakeAllConditionVariable(&workerThreadHolderPtr->mThreadReadyCond);

    for (;;)
    {
        for (;;)
        {
            SleepConditionVariableCS(
                &workerThreadHolderPtr->mStartTaskCond,
                &workerThreadHolderPtr->mLock,
                INFINITE);

            if (workerThreadHolderPtr->mGuardThreadState == GRD_TASKSTARTING)
                break;
        }

        workerThreadHolderPtr->mGuardThreadState = GRD_TASKWAITING;

        {
            BOOL isTaskFinishedOk = FALSE;

            for (;;)
            {
                isTaskFinishedOk =
                    SleepConditionVariableCS(
                        &workerThreadHolderPtr->mTaskFinishedCond,
                        &workerThreadHolderPtr->mLock,
                        taskExecutionTimeoutInMillisec);

                if (!isTaskFinishedOk)
                    break;
            }

            if (isTaskFinishedOk)
            {
                /* never happens in this test */
            }
            else
            {
                BOOL isClosed;
                TerminateThread(workerThreadHolderPtr->mHworkerThread, 0);

                /*if (RtlFreeUserThreadStack != NULL)
                    RtlFreeUserThreadStack(GetCurrentProcess(), workerThreadHolderPtr->mHworkerThread);*/

                isClosed = CloseHandle(workerThreadHolderPtr->mHworkerThread);

                workerThreadHolderPtr->mIsWorkerStarted = 0;

                workerThreadHolderPtr->mHworkerThread =
                    CreateThread(
                        NULL,
                        STK_SIZE,
                        WorkerThreadFun,
                        (PVOID)workerThreadHolderPtr,
                        STACK_SIZE_PARAM_IS_A_RESERVATION,
                        NULL);
            }
        }

        workerThreadHolderPtr->mGuardThreadState = GRD_READY;

        WakeAllConditionVariable(&workerThreadHolderPtr->mThreadReadyCond);
    }

    return 0;
}

void Start(WorkerThreadHolder *workerThreadHolderPtr)
{
    workerThreadHolderPtr->mGuardThreadState = GRD_IDLE;

    workerThreadHolderPtr->mIsWorkerStarted = 0;

    InitializeConditionVariable(&workerThreadHolderPtr->mThreadReadyCond);
    InitializeConditionVariable(&workerThreadHolderPtr->mStartTaskCond);
    InitializeConditionVariable(&workerThreadHolderPtr->mTaskFinishedCond);
    InitializeCriticalSection(&workerThreadHolderPtr->mLock);

    workerThreadHolderPtr->mHworkerThread =
        CreateThread(
            NULL,
            STK_SIZE,
            WorkerThreadFun,
            (LPVOID)workerThreadHolderPtr,
            STACK_SIZE_PARAM_IS_A_RESERVATION,
            NULL);

    workerThreadHolderPtr->mHworkerGroupThread =
        CreateThread(
            NULL,
            0,
            WorkerGuardThreadFun,
            (LPVOID)workerThreadHolderPtr,
            0,
            NULL);
}

void ExecuteTask(WorkerThreadHolder *workerThreadHolderPtr)
{
    assert(workerThreadHolderPtr->mHworkerThread != NULL);
    assert(workerThreadHolderPtr->mHworkerGroupThread != NULL);

    EnterCriticalSection(&workerThreadHolderPtr->mLock);

    for (;;)
    {
        if (workerThreadHolderPtr->mGuardThreadState == GRD_READY /* && workerThreadHolderPtr->mIsWorkerStarted != 0 */)
            break;

        SleepConditionVariableCS(
            &workerThreadHolderPtr->mThreadReadyCond,
            &workerThreadHolderPtr->mLock,
            INFINITE);
    }

    /* just poll */
    for (;;)
    {
        if (workerThreadHolderPtr->mIsWorkerStarted != 0)
            break;
    }

    workerThreadHolderPtr->mGuardThreadState = GRD_TASKSTARTING;

    WakeAllConditionVariable(&workerThreadHolderPtr->mStartTaskCond);

    LeaveCriticalSection(&workerThreadHolderPtr->mLock);
}

/*----------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int i;
    WorkerThreadHolder workerThreadHolder;

    /*
    HMODULE NTLibrary = GetModuleHandleW(L"ntdll.dll");
    RtlFreeUserThreadStack = (PRtlFreeUserThreadStack)GetProcAddress(NTLibrary, "RtlFreeUserThreadStack");
    */

    Start(&workerThreadHolder);

    for(i = 0;; ++i)
    {
        ExecuteTask(&workerThreadHolder);
        printf("%d Execution started...\n", i);
        /*fflush(stdout);*/
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Tested with Visual Studio 2015, vc command line:
/GS- /analyze- /W3 /Zc:wchar_t /ZI /Gm /Od /Fd"Debug\vc140.pdb" /Zc:inline /fp:precise /D "WIN32" /D "_DEBUG" /D "_CONSOLE" /D "_UNICODE" /D "UNICODE" /errorReport:prompt /WX- /Zc:forScope /Gd /Oy /MDd /Fa"Debug\" /nologo /Fo"Debug\" /Fp"Debug\ConsoleApplication1.pch"

linker:
/OUT:"C:\Users\cherney\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\ConsoleApplication1\Debug\ConsoleApplication1.exe" /MANIFEST /NXCOMPAT /PDB:"C:\Users\cherney\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\ConsoleApplication1\Debug\ConsoleApplication1.pdb" /DYNAMICBASE "kernel32.lib" "user32.lib" "gdi32.lib" "winspool.lib" "comdlg32.lib" "advapi32.lib" "shell32.lib" "ole32.lib" "oleaut32.lib" "uuid.lib" "odbc32.lib" "odbccp32.lib" /DEBUG /MACHINE:X86 /INCREMENTAL /PGD:"C:\Users\cherney\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\ConsoleApplication1\Debug\ConsoleApplication1.pgd" /SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE /MANIFESTUAC:"level='asInvoker' uiAccess='false'" /ManifestFile:"Debug\ConsoleApplication1.exe.intermediate.manifest" /ERRORREPORT:PROMPT /NOLOGO /TLBID:1

Comment: Any DLL could allocate memory in `DLL_THREAD_ATTACH` with the intention of freeing it in `DLL_THREAD_DETACH`. But terminating a thread does not send `DLL_THREAD_DETACH`. (It can't, since the thread that needs to send it no longer exists.)

Comment: @Raymond Chen In this example _WorkerThreadFun_ does not seem to load DLL nor use it

Comment: That's not what Raymond implied. Try to understand when DLL_THREAD_ATTACH is fired and who receives it. Have you considered not calling TerminateThread as the rules tell you not to.

Comment: @David Heffernan all DLLs which are loaded at the moment the thread fires, if I decipher your half-word right?

Comment: Win10 added support for releasing the address space for the thread stack.  But as it turned out, that just provided [another way](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39635817/17034) for programmers to shoot their leg clean off.  Don't do it is the only proper advice.

Comment: When a thread is created, every DLL present in the process receives a `DLL_THREAD_ATTACH` notification. That includes system DLLs like kernel32, as well as language support DLLs like msvcr70. This happens before the thread procedure runs. (Loading a DLL after a thread has started does not generate `DLL_THREAD_ATTACH` notifications for pre-existing threads.)

Comment: @Raymond Chen If I understand your idea right system DLLs which are already loaded/attached to the process at the moment the thread launches receive DLL_THREAD_ATTACH which makes some of those DLLs allocate resources per thread, that they have no chance to deallocate because of skipped balancing DLL_THREAD_DETACH if TerminateThread() is called instead of clean thread exit. That looks like the left hand of the system does not know what its right hand is doing. Well, I'm forced to move the unreliable functoin call into separate process.

Comment: The left hand assumes the right hand will finish the job, but you killed the right hand.

Comment: @Raymond Chen It is little bit frustrating for me 'cause I've expected the system to be something which has immanent internal coordination; so I've imagined the system to be the last and only instance to make decisions not relying on right nor left hand's assumtions. Let's try to live with what we have...

Comment: You cannot internally coordinate with an object that has already been destroyed. If code could execute in the context of a destroyed thread, then you would have the same problems all over again. The original designers felt strongly that there should not even be a TerminateThread function because there is no way to use it properly, but people complained that it was missing, so the designers reluctantly added it, and now you have people complaining that the thing they demanded cannot be used properly. Just don't use TerminateThread. There is no valid use case for it.

Answer (score 4):

'TerminateThread' is 'dangerous' and in fact some de-allocations may not occur (see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-terminatethread). Best to redesign the code to cleanly exit threads without the use of 'TerminateThread'.

Comment: Say I have an intention to run 3rd-party function inside _WorkerThreadFun_ and it freezes sometimes (but does not do any additional alloc) so its thread needs to be terminated.

Comment: @N.Cherney Then run it in another process and terminate the process if it misbehaves.

Comment: Any way "You should call TerminateThread only if you know exactly what the target thread is doing" the link says. Don't we know in example here what the target thread is doing?

Comment: Its easy to test. Just add a flag 'isTerminated' to your WorkerThreadHolder struct, set it to false when you start the thread, set it to true when you want to terminate the thread, and instead of TerminateThread call 'WaitForSingleObject(workerThreadHolderPtr->mHworkerThread, INFINITE)'. Exit the loop in the worker thread when the flag is set. What is the outome?

Comment: @J.R. Adding _volatile int mIsTerminated;_ to WorkerThreadHolder struct and making the loop in _WorkerThreadFun_ finite with _workerThreadHolderPtr->mIsTerminated = 1;_ after the loop while _workerThreadHolderPtr->mIsTerminated = 0;_ set before thread start (with _WaitForSingleObject(workerThreadHolderPtr->mHworkerThread, INFINITE);_ instead of _TerminateThread();_) leads to _printf("mIsTerminated=%d\n", workerThreadHolderPtr->mIsTerminated); fflush(stdout);_ printing _mIsTerminated=1_ after WaitForSingleObject as expected. But what is to test here?

Comment: It should all just run as before. The question is whether that fixes the memory leak.